Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $O$ be a point in its interior. $\angle BAO=\angle BCO,\angle BOC=90^\circ$ and $\angle ABO=\angle CAO, AC=2$, find $OC$
Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $O$ be a point in its interior. $\angle BAO=\angle BCO,$ $\angle BOC=90^\circ$ and $\angle ABO=\angle CAO,$ $AC=2$ cm, find $OC$.

I tried drawing some segment as following but I had no luck. I couldn't find any useful information from $\angle BOC=90$. Could you please give any hint?


This is an old problem. Here is a classic solution.
Continue $OC$ beyond $O$ for the same distance $DO=OC$. Since $BO\perp CD$, we have $\angle BDO=\angle BCO$. But then $D$ lies on the circumcircle $ABO$, since $\angle BAO=\angle BCO$.
From this we get that $\angle ADO=\angle ABO$. Since $\angle CAO = \angle ABO$, we get that triangles $ADC$ and $OAC$ are similar. Hence $$AC:DC=OC:AC \implies AC:(2OC)=OC:AC$$
$$\implies (AC:OC)^2=2 \implies AC=OC\sqrt2$$
$$\implies OC=\sqrt2.$$

I like this problem. Can you recommend some books with similar problems?

@JacobPhan This post is helpful. This book I like the most.

This book is wonderful. However, it's not easy to study this book since it doesn't contain many texts. For example, I don't understand the figure 1.11. Is there any books explain this book?

It’s the picture with quadrilateral and prove that four points are concyclic? Just use that the sum of angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$ and that a quadrilateral is concyclic iff the sum of the opposite angles is $180^\circ$.

@JacobPhan Also, I don’t know any book which specifically explains the Akopyan’s book.
